# Issues with my php table and javascript image slider on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, html

My website image slider works without the php section but with the php section it stops on one picture. I am new to javascript idk how to fix this.Any help will be great thanks in advance.

This is the javascript for the Image slider, works without the php bit.

```
<script>
    var imagecount = 1;
    var total = 6;



 window.setInterval(function photoA(){
        var image = document.getElementById('image');
        imagecount = imagecount + 1;
        if(imagecount > total){imagecount = 1;}
        if(imagecount < 1){imagecount = total;}
        image.src = "Images/Img"+ imagecount + ".jpg";
        },5000);
      </script>
```

This is the HTML and I am not sure whether this is the problem or not.

```
<body onLoad="photoA()"> 
<div id="slider">
<img src="Images/Img.jpg" id="image" >
</div>
<div id="tablearea">
<h1>Video Games</h1>
<h2> Action </h2>
```

This is the table in the HTML code.

```
<div id="wrapper">
<table>
        <tr>
            <th width="30%">Game Title</th>
            <th width="10%">Genre</th>
            <th width="10%">Rank</th>
            <th width="15%">Platform</th>
            <th width="10%">Year</th>
            <th width="25%">Publisher</th>
        </tr>
```

And this is the php which when added to the code the image slider stops.

```
<?php
    //make the connection
    include 'DB_connect.php';

    //Build our query
    $divisionQuery = "SELECT * FROM  `TABLE 1` WHERE  `Genre` LIKE  'action'";

    //Ask our database our query and display the results
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $divisionQuery);
    if (!$results) {
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysqli_errno();
        exit;
    }

    //Display the results row by row placing them in the table
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Game Title'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Genre'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Rank'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Platform'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Year'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['Publisher'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

Note: php table still shows up when on website with image slider.

Comment: Is the PHP code executing within the slider section? Is it possible to provide the full code so we can see the context of all the elements?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the php, do you get any clues looking at the developer console in chrome? https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: how do I show the whole code?

Comment: pres ctrl + shift +  j and see the console. maybe there's an error which stops the script.

Comment: wait so i used it on my website page: http://benji.freewebhost.co.nz/Games/genre_action.php. (btw it is for school) and it said Uncaught ReferenceError: photoA is not defined

Comment: Try validating your site here: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var imagecount = 1;
    var total = 6;



 window.setInterval(function photoA(){
        var image = document.getElementById('image');
        imagecount = imagecount + 1;
        if(imagecount > total){imagecount = 1;}

        //Problem Is Here, everytime here, imagecount=1; so, it will show that value only. So, check it properly.

        if(imagecount < 1){imagecount = total;}
        image.src = "Images/Img"+ imagecount + ".jpg";
        },5000);
      </script>
```